# Domain Driven Design - Shared entities across bounded contexts

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am new to domain driven design and trying to learn and implement in my project. My project structure up till now similar to this.

> Maintainance Folder
>     Maintainance.Data(Class
>   Library)
>    Maintainance.Domain(Class Library)
>           Maintainance.Domin.Tests(test project)
>
> MovieBooking Folder
>         MovieBooking.Data(Class
>   Library)
>            MovieBooking.Domain(Class Library)
>           MovieBooking.Domain.Tests(test project)
>
> SharedKernel
>            Common things
>
> Web Application 
>            MovieBooking MVC Web
>   Application(which have reference to MovieBooking Domain)

In `Maintainance` boundned context I am keeping all CRUD, GetAll type things for say Movie, Country, Category, Subcategory entities in `Maintainance` DBContext.
Now in `MovieBooking` data layer I will also need to use these entities (mostly to display name or dropdown fills in view, kind of subset needed - not all properties needed, only few like Id, name)

There are few ways I can access this entities in Movie booking Bounded Context

1. Via web services - Need to create web api for common entities like Movie,Country,Category,Subcategory and call web api in web project (to fill Dropdowns or get name from entities)
2. Via Reference Context (Seperate Dbcontext) - Need to configure Dbset and then map a database view (with only require fields) to Dbset
   Example :

   modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable(ViewName);

For (1) it can be long term implmentation solution for me
    (2) I have to create view (with only few properties) for each require table and it will increase my number of views in my DB drastically as I have enterprise level application.

Is there any other way I can achieve this? Anything I am missing in DDD to look for ?

Answer (score 1):

Option 2, while it will save you time, is actually a very bad idea from the DDD perspective as it allows for violations of the transactional boundary guarantees that each aggregate is meant to enforce\represent.

Option 1 seems a better option, although there are still quite a bit of wiggle room for interpretation based on your brief description of your proposed solution. If I understood correctly, it is generally recommended to follow the below:

1. Do not expose your aggregate state directly since this exposes internals and increases coupling. Simple create meaningful DTO's and use something like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to map your Aggregates to DTO's easilly and with little effort before sending it over.
2. Have a duplicate of the DTO definition in your client. This will reduce coupling and allow for easier deployments.

I *strongly* recommend reading the DDD [orange book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon-ebook/dp/B00BCLEBN8/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1502368474&sr=8-6&keywords=domain+driven+design) although I have to say that I cannot recall specifically on which chapter this is discussed. You will also benefit a lot by reading about hexagonal architecture (and I would search for that term in the orange book to find more info about your question).

There is actually one alternative that I can think of: if you're publishing events from your BC's you can create a workflow to translate the domain events to "public" events and then in the other BC listen for the public events that you need to and store the data that you need somewhere inside there. The difficulty of this ranges from very easy to quite problematic depending on your infrastructure. Be aware that it is not a very good idea to re-use your domain events for transmitting data to other BC's since this closely couples the two BC's.

I hope this helps. Please do not hesitate to elaborate if I did not understood the question well enough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am planning to have a look on the book (Orange) you suggested. 

For point (2)- configure Dbset and then map a database view (with only require fields) to Dbset, I have taken refernece from 
this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx and also course from pluralsight : Entity Framework in the Enterprise
Does that realted to your views on option 2? Please suggest if we are not on same path.

I feel I am kind of lost and looking for some light in dark :):) May be the book becomes light rays for me !!!

Comment: The point is isolation of business logic and the article you reference actually discusses splitting up a big dbcontext into smaller _independent_ ones which aligns perfectly with my recommendation above. Sharing tables allows for one BC to change the state of another, which really violates the possibility to guarantee transactional consistency from within the aggregate of the other BC.

Comment: To explain a bit further, you could share the db (but not the db context) and have separate db contexts in each BC, and the db contexts in different BC's would not be able to access the same tables. This is perfectly fine if you're not doing event sourcing btw, but I have found it is better to also isolate db's too if possible which helps to be able to deploy independently each service without affecting the other.